# ZEND project is loading only home page when we moved to new serevr and inner pages showing 404 error

Tags: zend-framework

```
  I got an issue in Zend frame work ,could you please help me ?
```

Issue :- I just tried to upload existing working zend project in my client server (its working fine in my server),then the client server I am getting 404 error page only , Except index page all other pages have this same issue . For testing I added new php files in the inner folders and tested.  its working fine. But zend format is not supported .

Comment: Did you copy the .htaccess-File as well? And are they evaluated in the clients server?

Comment: Yes. we tested it with and with out htaccess files. All the times it showing internal pages as 404. Only home page is loading only.Can u suggest what may be the reason?

Comment: are we talking about ZF1 or ZF2? And can you give us a rough layout of in which subfolders you get the 404 errors?

Comment: did you check to see if the server has mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Which 404 are you getting: Apache 404 or ZF 404?

Comment: so you write the same url as in your localhost ? (e.g. http://localhost/project/controller/action, http://website.com/project/controller/action) or are they different ?

Comment: In my local server it is working. When we moved to online server it shows 404 for internal pages.. My links like this: http://SITE_IP_ADDRESS/PROJECT_NAME/  it is loading home page well.But if I go to internal pages like http://SITE_IP_ADDRESS/PROJECT_NAME/index/index it is showing 404 error. We are using ZF1 only. It is throwing apache 404 error not the zend 404.Also mod_rewrite is on on our server. Any body please suggest what may be the reason for failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was you, I would check for the `mod_rewrite` and then, if it still doesn't work, check for your Apache vhost settings for this:

```
AllowOverride All
```

It may be set at "none" which would 'cause those problems... I got the same issue on my EC2 Ubuntu instance.

Comment: Yes . We checked the option AllowOverride All . It worked. Thanks for your help.